# React native redux saga TypeError

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

First of all, I apologise for the long post, I tried to shortened as much as possible.
I am trying to dispatch an action through saga, but I am getting **TypeError: resultFunc.apply is not a function** error.

The function sets a two variables in the Application reducer:

- isFirstTimer: `false`
- appLanguage: `en`

> Store/App/Actions.js

```
const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
  // Set language for the app from user
  firstTimer: ['language'],
  setDeviceLanguage: ['language'],
})

export const AppTypes = Types
export default Creators
```

> Store/App/Reducers.js

```
import { INITIAL_STATE } from './InitialState'
import { createReducer } from 'reduxsauce'
import { AppTypes } from './Actions'

export const firstTimer = (state, { language }) => ({
  ...state,
  isFristTimer: false,
  appLanguage: language,
})
export const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
  [AppTypes.FIRST_TIMER]: firstTimer,
  [AppTypes.SET_DEVICE_LANGUAGE]: setDeviceLanguage,
})
```

> Store/App/Selector.js

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

const isFristTimer = (state) => state.isFristTimer
const language = (state) => state.language

export const getFirstTimer = createSelector([isFristTimer, language])
```

> Sagas/AppSaga.js

```
import { put, select } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import * as Selectors from 'App/Stores/App/Selectors'

export function* firstTimer() {
  const whereTo = yield select(Selectors.getFirstTimer)
  const language = yield select(Selectors.language)
  Reactotron.log('getFirstTimer value', whereTo)
  Reactotron.log('language value', language)
  // When those operations are finished we redirect to the main screen
}
```

**Note: The two variables from the selectors do not log in Reactotron!!.**

> Sagas/index.js

```
import { takeLatest, all } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { firstTimer } from './AppSaga'
import { AppTypes } from 'App/Stores/App/Actions'

export default function* root() {
  yield all([
    // Call `firstTimer()` when a `FIRST_TIMER` action is triggered
    takeLatest(AppTypes.FIRST_TIMER, firstTimer),
  ])
```

In my **rootScreen.js**, I am rendering conditionally according to the mentioned above **firstTime** variable

```
  componentDidMount() {
    Reactotron.log('our state : ' + this.props.app)
  }

  _setLanguage(language) {
    this.props.setFirstTimer(language)
  }

  render() {
    const { isFristTimer } = this.props.app
    if (isFristTimer) {
      return (
        <View style={Helpers.fill}>
          <ImageBackground source={Images.firstTimerBg} style={Helpers.fullSize}>
            <View
              style={[
                Style.buttonWrapper,
                Helpers.mainCenter,
                Helpers.mainSpaceBetween,
                Helpers.row,
                Metrics.mediumHorizontalMargin,
              ]}
            >
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this._setLanguage('en')}
                style={[Style.buttonContainer, Helpers.center]}
              >
                <Text style={Fonts.normal}>{Words.english}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this._setLanguage('ar')}
                style={[Style.buttonContainer, Helpers.center]}
              >
                <Text style={Fonts.normal}>{Words.arabic}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </ImageBackground>
        </View>
      )
    }
    return (
      <View style={Helpers.fill}>
        <AppNavigator
          // Initialize the NavigationService (see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html)
          ref={(navigatorRef) => {
            NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef)
          }}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

> The end result :

[image]

If I dismiss the error, the application is no longer rendering the first block, and it renders the AppNavigator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `getFirstTimer` selector - the second argument to `createSelector` should be the `resultFunc` (that you see referenced in your error) that takes the results of other selectors it depends on and returns a value. See https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#createselectorinputselectors--inputselectors-resultfunc. Updating `getFirstTimer` should resolve the issue:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

const isFristTimer = (state) => state.isFristTimer
const language = (state) => state.language

export const getFirstTimer = createSelector(
  [isFristTimer, language],
  // here is where the result func is added to the selector definition
  (isFristTimer, language) => ({
    isFristTimer,
    language,
  })
)
```